# Delimiter Matching using Stack

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, stack

I have a small problem here you might consider answering;

Here is the code;

```
public void analyze (String input, int length, int j){
    if (j == length){
        return;
    }
    if(input.charAt(j) == '{' || input.charAt(j) == '(')
        push(input.charAt(j));
    else
        pop();
    j++;    

    analyze (input, length, j);
}
```

Output:

```
Original List: {()}



List: {
```

Well, the problem is the List should be empty but I couldn't seem to find the solution.

Thank you in advance.

Here is the full code:
http://pastebin.com/nXc79gHf

Comment: Looks like length is set to input.length()-1 before first call of analyze(). But I'm not sure, because I need more code to understand.

Comment: Where do you ever look for a closing brace or parenthesis? Do you think that might have something to do with your problem?

Comment: @JimGarrison I think if its not open then it pops

Comment: What if it is neither an open or close delimiter?  Also, you have not shown what you do with the results of your analysis, and how the output is produced.  Without that we're all just guessing.

Comment: @SergeyChechenev when I added - 1 in if `(j == length - 1)` the output is `List: {(`

Comment: @JimGarrison I think i will try to improve my conditioning statements, hopefully it will work

thanks

Comment: Please post code in the question, not in pastebin.

Comment: You haven't shown us the original call to `analyze()`.  How can we tell what's going on without that?

Answer (score 0):

> Assuming your input contain only `'}', '{'` and `'(', ')'` characters.

replace by below code (assuming `push()` and `pop()` do work fine)...

```
public void analyze(String input, int length, int j){
        if (j >= length) return;
        if(input.charAt(j) == '{' || input.charAt(j) == '(')
            push(input.charAt(j));
        else if(input.charAt(j) == '}' || input.charAt(j) == ')')
            pop();
        analyze (input, length, ++j);
    }
```

call by using `analyze(input, input.length(), 0);`

Ex. `{()}`